# Accounting for Spatial Autocorrelation in a GAM: including coordinates of points as smooth terms is not working

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, beta-regression

I have been trying to use GAM/GAMMs to account for spatial autocorrelation in residuals of a GLMM. I have explained my data in detail in [this Stack Exchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492250/how-should-i-deal-with-spatial-autocorrelation-in-beta-glmm-glmmtmb-bird-div). The question also demonsrates how I figured out that I had spatial autocorrelation. The GLMM formulation I used was (no spatial terms here):

```
mod_glmm <- glmmTMB(diversity_index ~ year + (1 | square_ID), family = 
              beta_family(), data = data)
```

I have formulated my GAMMs as shown below. My intention was to remove the spatial dependence, which is of no interest to me; I only interested in the effect of "year" predictor here, which is a 2-level factor.

```
    mod_gam <- gam(data = data, diversity_index ~ s(longitude, latitude) + year + s(square_ID, bs = "re"), 
family = betar(link = "logit"), method = "REML")
```

After building this model, I have compared the correlograms (min. distance between sites is 0.19 - mean is around 1.3) and variograms of the GLMM and its GAMM counterpart, and it looks like I could not successfully get rid of the spatial autocorrelation. Actually, it may even be worse. See the plots below. My question is: **what am I doing wrong here? Is there something I'm missing?**

Data for reproducibility:

```
square_ID   year    longitude   latitude    diversity_index
SUG1    1998    31,26   37,847  0,676484848484849
SUG3    1998    31,586  37,717  0,713333333333333
SUG4    1998    31,597  37,392  0,719151515151515
SUH2    1998    31,226  38,034  0,674545454545455
SUH4    1998    31,491  38,033  0,698787878787879
SVF1    1998    32,069  37,04   0,615393939393939
SVG1    1998    32,149  37,719  0,713333333333333
SVG2    1998    32,148  37,301  0,698787878787879
SVG3    1998    32,716  37,722  0,738545454545455
SVG4    1998    32,731  37,346  0,743393939393939
SVH2    1998    32,194  38,019  0,688121212121212
SVH3    1998    32,76   38,637  0,655151515151515
SVH4    1998    32,73   38,165  0,702666666666667
SVJ3    1998    32,804  39,367  0,441818181818182
SVJ4    1998    32,816  39,054  0,516484848484849
SWF1    1998    33,312  36,992  0,644484848484849
SWF3    1998    33,693  37,01   0,631878787878788
SWG1    1998    33,284  37,722  0,700727272727273
SWG2    1998    33,282  37,272  0,723030303030303
SWG3    1998    33,851  37,719  0,687151515151515
SWG4    1998    33,842  37,272  0,720121212121212
SWH1    1998    33,263  39,01   0,694909090909091
SWH2    1998    33,676  38,925  0,661939393939394
SWH3    1998    34,385  37,744  0,704606060606061
SWH4    1998    34,279  37,349  0,689090909090909
SWJ2    1998    34,776  37,85   0,561090909090909
SWJ4    1998    34,409  38,448  0,666787878787879
SXG1    1998    34,427  38,164  0,735636363636364
SXG2    1998    34,793  38,45   0,738545454545455
SXG3    1998    34,837  38,126  0,649333333333333
SXH1    1998    33,287  38,623  0,734666666666667
SXH2    1998    33,285  38,173  0,774424242424242
SXH3    1998    33,826  38,598  0,693939393939394
SXH4    1998    33,856  38,17   0,724969696969697
SUG1    2018    31,26   37,847  0,956727272727273
SUG3    2018    31,586  37,717  0,853939393939394
SUG4    2018    31,597  37,392  0,804484848484848
SUH2    2018    31,226  38,034  0,984848484848485
SUH4    2018    31,491  38,033  0,885939393939394
SVF1    2018    32,069  37,04   0,725939393939394
SVG1    2018    32,149  37,719  0,847151515151515
SVG2    2018    32,148  37,301  0,811272727272727
SVG3    2018    32,716  37,722  0,850060606060606
SVG4    2018    32,731  37,346  0,855878787878788
SVH2    2018    32,194  38,019  0,825818181818182
SVH3    2018    32,76   38,637  0,812242424242424
SVH4    2018    32,73   38,165  0,852
SVJ3    2018    32,804  39,367  0,675515151515152
SVJ4    2018    32,816  39,054  0,713333333333333
SWF1    2018    33,312  36,992  0,664848484848485
SWF3    2018    33,693  37,01   0,811272727272727
SWG1    2018    33,284  37,722  0,819030303030303
SWG2    2018    33,282  37,272  0,82969696969697
SWG3    2018    33,851  37,719  0,783151515151515
SWG4    2018    33,842  37,272  0,815151515151515
SWH1    2018    33,263  39,01   0,82969696969697
SWH2    2018    33,676  38,925  0,804484848484848
SWH3    2018    34,385  37,744  0,828727272727273
SWH4    2018    34,279  37,349  0,813212121212121
SWJ2    2018    34,776  37,85   0,751151515151515
SWJ4    2018    34,409  38,448  0,794787878787879
SXG1    2018    34,427  38,164  0,774424242424242
SXG2    2018    34,793  38,45   0,784121212121212
SXG3    2018    34,837  38,126  0,784121212121212
SXH1    2018    33,287  38,623  0,848121212121212
SXH2    2018    33,285  38,173  0,823878787878788
SXH3    2018    33,826  38,598  0,909212121212121
SXH4    2018    33,856  38,17   0,840363636363636
```

[image]
[image]
[image]